# Docker ubuntu python環境でScapyの実行について

Tags: python, python3, ubuntu, docker

以下の環境でPython、scapy をインストールしscapyをimportし実行を行っていますが、scapyが呼び出せていないようです。
原因が、改善策が分かる方、ご教示ください。

なお、`pull ubuntu` してきたubuntuのDockerイメージには、vim、python、pip等が入っていなかったため、root権限で自分でインストールしました。

私が実施した内容を以下に記載致します。

### 環境

Windows 10 Pro（ホストOS）
WSL2
Ubuntu（22.04.1 LTS）
Docker

```
# docker pull ubuntu:latest
# docker container run -itd  --name myubu ubuntu:latest
# docker exec -it myubu bash
```

```
# apt-get update
```

pythonが入っているか確認→入っていなかった

```
root@22c1e6376c8b:/# python3 -V
bash: python3: command not found
```

pythonをインストール（エラーなくインストール完了）

```
# apt-get install python3
```

```
# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

```
# python3 -V
Python 3.10.6
```

pipのインストール（エラーなくインストール完了）

```
# apt install python3-pip
```

scapyのインストール（エラーなくインストール完了）

```
# pip3 install scapy-python3
```

```
# pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.0.2
setuptools 59.6.0
wheel      0.37.1
```

### pythonが正常に起動するか確認（エラーなく実行）

/usr/src/test.pyを作成し実行

.pyファイルの内容↓

```
print("Docker")
```

```
# python3 test.py
表示結果↓
Docker
```

### scapyの確認

/usr/src/testScapy.pyを作成し実行
.pyファイルの内容↓

```
from scapy.all import *
print("Scapyy")
```

testScapy.pyの実行

```
# python3 testScapy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/testScapy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
```

Answer (score 0):

## 原因？

最後のエラーの文章が途中で切れているので想像ですが、途中まではDockerコンテナ内部で作業ができているものの、途中でWSL2に出てしまい、結果 WSL2 側で `python3` や `scapy` がインストールされているもののコンテナ内部には `scapy` が入っておらず、そこでエラーが出ているのではないでしょうか。

おそらく、 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'` というエラーが続いているものだと思われます。

## 解決方法

現在のエラーについては、コンテナ内で `pip3 install scapy-python3` を再度行えば解決できそうです。

また、次のことを確実にしてください。

- Docker コンテナ内部で `scapy` をインストールしている
- シェルでの作業が Docker コンテナ内部なのか、 WSL2なのかを明確にする

`Dockerfile` を記述し、 `docker exec` を行わずに必要なライブラリがインストールされているイメージを作成するのも有効です。